# How can I retrieve all values from a Map using EL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a SortedMap which I'm populating in my service classes, I want to display all the values stored in the map in a sorted order. How can I do that using EL (Expression language).
Also how can I access the keys?

Thanks for the help.

Ravi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So:

```
<ol>
  <c:forEach items="${myMap}" var="item">
    <li><c:out value="${item.key}"/>=<c:out value="${item.value}"/></li>
  </c:forEach>
</ol>
```